# Problema al enviar valor de un combobox y mysql a otra página

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Estoy creando una página de control de gastos de viaje para mi, intento que através de un combobox que recoge datos de un campo de una BBDD de mysql, lo envíe a otra página que con un GET pueda realizar un select where con el valor del campo que se ha enviado desde la página inicial.

El problema que veo es que no se está enviando el valor del campo, no se el porque. El código es el que utilizo para eliminar registro, el cual funciona correctamente.

Este es el código de la página que contiene el combobox:

```
<form name="formulario" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<br>
    Ver viaje:
    <select name="tipo" >
      <option value="0">Selecciona</option>
      <?php
      require("pages/conn/connection.php");
        $query = "select DISTINCTROW viaje_nombre from viaje";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['viaje_nombre'].'</option>';
        }

      ?>

    </select>
      <!--<input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Ir" />-->
      <a class="boton_eliminar" href="gastos.php?Reg=<?php echo $row['viaje_nombre']; ?>">Ir</a>

  </form>
```

Este es parte del código que recibe el valor:

```
    require("../conn/connection.php");
      if(isset($_GET['Reg'])){

      $Reg = $_GET['Reg'];
                $query_paginador = mysqli_query($conn,"Select count(*) as registros_totales from viaje where viaje_nombre = $Reg");
                $result_paginador = mysqli_fetch_array($query_paginador);
                $total_registro = $result_paginador['registros_totales'];
```

Comment: Cambia el formulario a método _GET_, agrega `action=gastos.php`, cambia el nombre del select a _Reg_ y, en lugar de enlace, usa un botón tipo _submit_. De otra forma, tendrías que usar Javascript para actualizar el enlace y no tendría sentido el formulario.

Answer (score 0):

Es esto lo que me indicas:

```
<form action="gastos.php" name="formulario" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <br>
          Ver viaje:
          <select id="tipo" name="Reg" >
            <option value="0">Selecciona</option>

            <?php
              require("pages/conn/connection.php");
              $query = "select DISTINCTROW viaje_nombre from viaje";
              $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
              //$viaje_nombre = $_POST['viaje_nombre']
              while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
                  echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['viaje_nombre'].'</option>';
              }
            ?>

          </select>
            <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Ir" />
            <!--<a class="boton_eliminar" href="javascript:capturar()">Ir</a>-->

        </form>
        <?php
          if(isset($_POST['submit'])){                 
              header("location:pages/viajes/gastos.php?Reg=$row['viaje_nombre']");                  
        }
        ?>
```

Al hacer esto recibo el siguiente error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /volume1/web/viajes/index.php on line 103

La linea 103 es

> header("location:pages/viajes/gastos.php?Reg=$row['viaje_nombre']");

Gracias por la rápida contestación